# ACR not found In Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-macros

Can someone help me with this. I know this question has been asked and being marked as solved a hundred of times.

```
The type or namespace name 'Acr' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
```

I have already done the which answers have told me to like delete bin, packages folder, debug folder and restore. Recently I have updated my VS for MAC and Mono also.

```
Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac (Preview)
Version 8.3 Preview (8.3 build 867)
Installation UUID: dfffb47a-ce0b-4228-8a57-e96d0dda9e55
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 5.16.0.5 (d16-3 / 26f04c54)

    Package version: 604000081

Mono Framework MDK
Runtime:
    Mono 6.4.0.81 (2019-06/f55e0a671c0) (64-bit)
    Package version: 604000081

NuGet
Version: 5.2.0.6067

.NET Core
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    2.1.12
    2.1.11
    2.1.9
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.701/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    2.1.701
    2.1.700
    2.1.505
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.4.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.6.10
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 10.2 (14490.120)
Build 10E125

Xamarin.Mac
Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

Xamarin.Android
Version: 9.5.0.27 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d16-3/16c4494
Android SDK: /Users/ashish/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        8.1 (API level 27)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 28.0.3
SDK Build Tools Version: 27.0.3

Build Information: 
Mono: mono/mono/2019-02@e6f5369c2d2
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/d16-3@5836f58
LibZipSharp: grendello/LibZipSharp/d16-3@71f4a94
LibZip: nih-at/libzip/rel-1-5-1@b95cf3f
ProGuard: xamarin/proguard/master@905836d
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.27.1@8212a2d
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-3@cb41333

Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Users/ashish/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
1.8.0-25
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 1.4.0.8
Hash: 28342d0
Branch: remotes/origin/backport-pr-235-to-d16-3~2
Build date: 2019-07-18 16:54:46 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 1.2.0.75
Hash: bf6d603
Branch: remotes/origin/backport-pr-369-to-d16-3~1
Build date: 2019-07-18 16:55:08 UTC

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 12.16.0.5 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 26f04c54
Branch: d16-3
Build date: 2019-06-28 01:31:14-0400

Xamarin Designer
Version: 16.3.0.17
Hash: 73f0a446c
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3-release-8.3-p1
Build date: 2019-07-22 17:05:22 UTC

Build Information
Release ID: 803000867
Git revision: ab4af85ea561e474b545e0eada75c5bfe8a92297
Build date: 2019-07-24 14:13:44+00
Build branch: release-8.3-preview1
Xamarin extensions: 45290013e165bcd2db7acbb310e0c16bfe04f0c3

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.14.6
Darwin 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0
    Thu Jun 20 18:42:21 PDT 2019
    root:xnu-4903.270.47~4/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Enabled user installed extensions
Team Foundation Version Control for TFS and Azure DevOps 0.4.4.5
```

The solution doesn't build even. I cant even downgrade the `MONO` to the lower version as suggested in some of the answers.

Comment: I have this here, the nuget name is SignaturePad.Xamarin.Forms.PCL, but i am not sure it's the same as yours.

Comment: @Jimbot Did you got any solution ?

Comment: It's look like your project doesn't have this nuget package referenced, mine work well. Just try to download it via the nugets manager.

Comment: @Jimbot Have downloaded all the packages

Comment: Acr is definitely not a .net or mono namespace, so it must come from somewhere else.